# Spree Solidus : Merge address and delivery steps during checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am trying to merge the address and delivery and make it as a single step as address during solidus checkout process. Facing few issues. I followed following process :

`remove_checkout_step :delivery` in *order_decorator*

add the following code in overridden *_address.html*

`<%= form.fields_for :shipments do |ship_form| %>
            <div class="shipment">
              <h5 class="stock-shipping-method-title"><%= Spree.t(:shipping_method) %></h5>
              <ul class="field radios shipping-methods">
                <%= fine %>
                <% ship_form.object.shipping_rates.each do |rate| %>
                    <li class="shipping-method">
                      <label>
                        <%= ship_form.radio_button :selected_shipping_rate_id, rate.id %>
                        <span class="rate-name"><%= rate.name %></span>
                        <span class="rate-cost"><%= rate.display_cost %></span>
                      </label>
                    </li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
        <% end %>`

But the radio buttons for selecting the shipping methods don't appear. I even called the *before_delivery* callback in *before_address* of checkout_controller.

Any suggestions are very helpful

Answer (score 1):

First things first, shipments are only created when a ship address is specified hence this should be after `address` step.

Maybe you can have this form disabled in address step and enable it when address is filled (saved). In this case you do not have to remove delivery step rather go with usual flow of spree and just add an ajax request to save address and move to delivery step in between which then enable's the shipment's form.

Also, above solution ensures that admin flow of order creation/updation remains unchanged.

FYI: By removing delivery step you have basically removed creation of shipment from your application but thats not what you want, right ?

Comment: Priyank Gupta in my case, I dont want shipment so I have removed delivery step but its affecting my stock management flow. Any suggestion